# MVC 4 DB access design decision

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently i'm updating a project from MVC 2 to MVC 4 and I'm about to swap the custom ORM/data access "layer" with EF 4.3.1 ( upgrading to 5 when it's out) and as i currently understand most of the controllers use functions from another file which are wrappers to DB queries and stored procedures.

So , my question is this : Should i delete this file with the wrapper functions and directly use EF to fetch the data from the controllers or should i just delete the contents of each function and replace it with EF code ?

Any other design tips you could give me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a repository pattern (exactly what you are doing) allows you be more flexible in the future as you can swap out that single file with code that uses NHibernate or connects to MySql for example. This way your code isn't tightly coupled with EF and you can more easily move away from it should you want to.

Having said that, there is obviously some coding overhead involved with the repository pattern and if you're not concerned with coupling your code tightly with EF then you can certainly go the latter route.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the this is simply matter of choice, both seem valid for certain scenarios. That said, I think that for larger project using classes that simplify access to the database, provide common functionality and can be more easily swapped for classes wrapping other data providers (like Hibernate) when you would need to.

Plus you might add additional data providers (for example consuming other sites' APIs) and if you also included these data providers directly into your controllers, you would produce very hard to read code.

This approach will also significantly simplify your controllers, which might not seem as a big deal at first, but as more controllers with significantly functionality will be added, the added value becomes clear.